# Why are probability problems involving combinations often solved indirectly?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say you have a box with 25 cell phones in it, of which 2 are defective. If a person selects 10 cell phones at random, without replacement, what is the probability that both defective cell phones will be selected?

I've only seen problems of this sort solved "indirectly". For example, one would solve for the probability of selecting 8 *non-defective* cell phones and not for selecting the 2 *defective* cell phones. **Why is this? How do you solve for selecting the 2 *defective* cell phones directly?**

---

If it helps, here is how I've seen these types of problems solved. If 8 out of the 10 cell phones are *non-defective*, then the remaining 2 cell phones selected must be the *defective* cell phones. So, you first figure out the total number of ways selecting 10 cell phones at random from 25 cell phones (without replacement) which is 25 choose 10 or $\binom{25}{10} = 3,268,760$ using the binomial coefficient formula. Then, calculate the number of ways to select 8 *non-defective* cell phones from 23 total non-defective cell phones (25 total cell phones minus 2 defective cell phones) so $\binom{23}{8}=490,314$. Therefore, the probability of selecting the 8 *non-defective* cell phones is $490,314 / 3,268,760 = 0.15$ which also equals the probability of selecting 2 *defective* cell phones. But, I've never seen this type of problem solved for in a "direct" manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $X$ of defective phones selected has a hypergeometric distribution. In R, the direct computation for $P(X = 2)$ is as
follows:

```
dhyper(2, 2,23, 10)
[1] 0.15
```

The computation amounts to $$P(X = 2) = \frac{{2\choose 2}{23\choose 8}}{{25 \choose 10}} = 0.15,$$ where ${2 \choose 2}= 1$ may be omitted.

```
choose(2,2)*choose(23,8)/choose(25,10)
[1] 0.15
```

If you ask for the probability of getting exactly one defective phone
then it's 0.5. Solution using binomial coefficients will have ${2 \choose 1} = 2$ in the numerator, which can't be omitted:
$$P(X = 1) = \frac{{2\choose 1}{23\choose 9}}{{25 \choose 10}} = 0.5.$$

```
dhyper(1,2,23,10)
[1] 0.5
choose(2,1)*choose(23,9)/choose(25,10)
[1] 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you! I simply failed to recognize that 2 choose 2 is obviously 1 and can be omitted, hence, why I never see it in the solutions.